# Adherent and isolated point

Tags: general-topology

Is every isolated point of a set A is its adherent point?
I'm cofused about  this point . Every adherent point which is not limit point is isolated but is the converse true?

Comment: "Is every isolated point of a set A is its adherent point?" please form valid sentences.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, an isolated point of a set $A$ in a topological space is a member of $A$. Therefore, trivially, it is also an adherent point, because every open set containing it, contains a member of $A$, namely, itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, trivially all points of $A$ are adherent points of $A$, but indeed there are two subtypes among them: the isolated points of $A$ and the limit points of $A$ ( that are also a point of $A$, so $A’ \cap A$). This is clear by the definitions.